# Formula for the probability that m randomly chosen vertices of a regular n-gon form an m-gon who’s center isn’t contained in the n-gon

Tags: probability, geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry

The title pretty much says my question. More specifically, I was asked the following question: Consider 256 randomly-chosen vertices of a regular 2019-gon. What is the probability that the 256-gon does not contain the center of the original 2019-gon in its interior? I would guess it might be easier to find the probability that the center *is* contained, perhaps using induction? But I am unsure of how to prove such a formula

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this a regular 2019-gon? If not, I don't see how it could be possible to give a formula in $m$ and $n$ only.

Comment: Yes, and the original n-gon (or in the specific problem the 2019-gon) is assumed to be regular. I forgot to include that important detail, my bad.

Comment: Please clarify the question accordingly. The question should be self-contained and not rely on the comments to be understood.

Comment: The question heading and description are now clarified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centre of the regular $2019$-gon is not contained in the $256$-gon exactly if all $256$ vertices are in one semicircle. We can split this event into $256$ events, namely that all $256$ vertices are in the semicircle clockwise from a given vertex. These $256$ events are mutually disjoint and together exhaust the event that the vertices are in any semicircle. The probability that all $256$ vertices are in the semicircle clockwise of a given vertex is

$$
\frac{\binom{1009}{255}}{\binom{2018}{255}}\;.
$$

Thus the probability for the centre not to be contained in the $256$-gon is

\begin{eqnarray}
&&256\cdot\frac{\binom{1009}{255}}{\binom{2018}{255}}
\\
&=&\frac{15865309465706232832981575559545291327395059198698618829139882039912932479498809443780224}{361558702088650776590352424439455000541031270078646733695481454328575304744288927295247413821425064475196440245870105015601861838259842130006107502554951092437472018066755}
\\[10pt]
&\approx&
4.4\cdot10^{-83}\;.
\end{eqnarray}